# how to make iframe height same as browser

Tags: css, iframe, browser

I am using `<iframe src="https://example.com" width="100%" height="610"></iframe>`
i want to make the `iframe` height same as my browser, I don't know how, i tried the following and none of it works:

1. `height="100%"`
2. `height="calc(100vh)"`

also i src my iframe into my left nav bar and even i change my navbar height, still doesn't change iframe height even when i put `height="100%"`.

Pls help me, i prefer using css over javascript, but if i have to i am happy to use javascript .

Answer (score 0):

FYI you only need to use `calc()` when doing math, like `calc(100vh - 100px)`

`vh` is a part of CSS3 so using the `height=` attribute won't work (it only supports pixels or % in HTML4 and only pixels in HTML5); you need to use `style="height: 100vh;"` instead.

I would get out of the habit of using `width`, `height`, or any other attribute that changes the appearance of an element and use CSS exclusively, via either `class` or `style`.

Comment: I think it definitely works by itself, but now i have another problem, i embeded iframe into side navbar, and iframe css `100vh` seems to be restricted by navbar css height setting(i tried 200vh-500vh, `vh` is no longer dynamic to browser but fixed height within the navbar), i tried all sorts of ways to adjust sidebar css to make it the same height as browser, none of them works. Can you take a quick look at my navbar css in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxXwLw and see where went wrong? thanks by the way for your solution.